# Social Engine <body> tags and pasting code in the body

Tags: socialengine

I have a Social Engine website and I need to post a script into  tags — just before the closing. The specific instruction for me is the following:

"Copy & paste the code below right before the closing  tag at the end of your code."

I don't know how to do this, as Social Engine is set up in a way that the source code is not easily accessible.

We host in AWS.

The specific question is, What are the step-by-step instructions I need to post a script just before the closing  tag?

Thank you for any help in advance :)

Comment: What kind of Social Engine are you using? Please read the documentation for that and you should find the answer. May be you have to change templates or some pre-defined variables in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to application->modules->Core->layouts->scripts->default.tpl

and check line no:189 for body tag.

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where you Say "go to application" do you mean in the admin panel? Because I can't see a tab for application. Or do you mean in AWS?

Comment: I need more help I'm afraid. I cannot find 'application' in the AWS console. I sign in to the console, but I do  not know where to start. Where do I find 'Application'?